# UI Automation supported pattern but shows invalid operation error while using pattern

Tags: c#, .net, windows, invalidoperationexception, microsoft-ui-automation

I have developed uiautomation (C#, .NET 4.5) for a third-party windows application. However the application was upgraded to new version. Since then, my automation application shows that the UI control support the patterns, but when I try to use them, it gives Invalid Operation error. One example...

```
UIA_refreshRMSPositionsBtn = 
       UIA_RMSwindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, 
       new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "1025"));

ClickButton(UIA_refreshRMSPositionsBtn);

public static void ClickButton(AutomationElement automationElement) {
     var invokePattern = 
           automationElement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;

     invokePattern.Invoke();
}
```

The Button shows that it supports the Invoke pattern (and was working earlier). Now it shows Invalid Operation error. The same happens for some text boxes, which show support for both Value and Text patterns, but give same error while trying to use those patterns.

Any clues what I need to try to it work?

Comment: Is it on Windows 8 by any chance? Do you run as admin?

Comment: @Moshisho I'm getting this error as well on Windows 8.. When running the application as "administrator", the issue is not being seen..